# Mapbasic Error - Alter Object cannot operate on an unitialized object variable

Tags: mapbasic

I get this error when running an mbx in Mapbasic

```
   Include "MapBasic.def"
   Include "Menu.def"

'assign brush/pen symbology for all but easements
        dim b1 as Brush
        b1 = makebrush (1,16777136,-1)  'Black colour, no fill
    dim p1 as Pen
        p1 = makepen (1,2,0)            'Black line
    dim x as Integer
    dim oUpdateObj as Object


    'Change Fill and Pen
    Open Table StrPathOt+"Easements.TAB" Interactive

    'Easements
    Select * from Easements where Str$(obj) = "Region" into NewStyle
        Fetch first from NewStyle
    x = 1
    Do
        oUpdateObj = NewStyle.obj
            Alter Object oUpdateObj Info OBJ_INFO_BRUSH, b1
            Alter Object oUpdateObj Info OBJ_INFO_PEN, p1

            Update NewStyle set Obj = oUpdateObj where RowID = x

            x = x + 1

            Fetch next from NewStyle

    Loop while x <= TableInfo(NewStyle,TAB_INFO_NROWS)
    Commit Table Easements
```

The issue reported is on this line
[image]
    Alter Object oUpdateObj Info OBJ_INFO_BRUSH, b1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out an answer based on feedback in [LI360](https://li360.pitneybowes.com/s/question/0D58000004Si96gCAB/mapbasic-error-alter-object-cannot-operate-on-an-unitialized-object-variable?t=1535340095847)

Here's the code if anyone is interested.

---

```
Declare Sub Assign_Symbology(ByVal FileName as String, ByVal b1 as Brush, ByVal p1 as Pen)

Declare Sub Main


Sub Assign_Symbology (ByVal FileName as String, ByVal b1 as Brush, ByVal p1 as Pen)

Dim   oUpdateObj as Object

Dim x as Integer


Open Table FileName as NewStyle

Fetch first from NewStyle

Do Until EOT(NewStyle)


 oUpdateObj = NewStyle.obj


 x = NewStyle.ROWID


 Alter Object oUpdateObj Info OBJ_INFO_BRUSH, b1


 Alter Object oUpdateObj Info OBJ_INFO_PEN, p1


 Update NewStyle set Obj = oUpdateObj where RowID = x


 Fetch next from NewStyle


Loop

Commit Table NewStyle

Close Table NewStyle

End Sub


Sub Main

Dim StrPathOt, FileName as String

StrPathOt="G:\Projects\076_Monthly_DCDB_Update\Working\current\output\"


   dim b1 as Brush

   dim p1 as Pen

   'Assing file to modify and symbology to set


      'Easements

      FileName = StrPathOt+"Easements.TAB"

      p1 = makepen (1,2,0)         'Black line

      b1 = makebrush (1,16777136,-1)   'Black colour, no fill

      Call Assign_Symbology (FileName, b1, p1)

      Print " Assigned symbology for: "+FileName

      'Drainage

      FileName = StrPathOt+"Drainage_DCDB"

      Call Assign_Symbology (FileName, b1, p1)

      Print " Assigned symbology for: "+FileName
```

---

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to this approach, and a more efficient way to do this as MapInfo can deal with looping through the table internally, is to extract the style update code into a separate function which you can then call directly from an `Update Table` statement.

```vb
Sub Assign_Symbology (ByVal fileName as String, ByVal b1 as Brush, ByVal p1 as Pen)

    Open Table fileName as NewStyle
    Update NewStyle Set obj = UpdateStyle(obj, b1, p1)

End Sub

Function UpdateStyle(ByVal objTarget as Object, ByVal b1 as Brush, ByVal p1 as Pen) as Object

    Alter Object objTarget Info OBJ_INFO_BRUSH, b1
    Alter Object objTarget Info OBJ_INFO_PEN, p1

    UpdateStyle = objTarget

End Function
```